# Is there a reason why this code is casting to 'unknown' as an intermediary type?

Tags: typescript

I'm reading through the source code for this repo: https://github.com/cwayfinder/on-property-change/blob/master/src/on-property-change.ts

and I see:

```
function normaliseProps(props: string | string[]): string[] {
    if (Array.isArray(props)) {
        return props as unknown as string[];
    } else {
        return [props as unknown as string];
    }
}
```

Is there any reason for casting to `unknown` here?

As far as I can tell, it can be removed:

```
function normaliseProps(props: string | string[]): string[] {
    if (Array.isArray(props)) {
        return props as string[];
    } else {
        return [props as string];
    }
}
```

Is there any benefit of using the former code?

Comment: As far as I can see, you don't need any casts [at all](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGOAnAtgQwDYwM4CmACqnAA54AUZpFAXInlKjGAOaIA+jzrbA2gF0AlAyYt2QxAG8AsAChESxDGCJKAQVSpMATwB0+LTt3VaeYcJkLltxKgJQQqJDXJ4A3DeUBfRAWxCa0U7JQcnF0R+NwpBLxClHwUfIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type assertions so require some relationship between the source and target type.  So you can't assert a `string` is a `number` ([ex](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAbgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgXggIjwG4AoUSNHaCAQ3gjQFcBbAIxCSA)). The common escape hatch for this is to assert to `unknown` first and then you can assert to anything

```
let v: string = "";
let n = v as unknown as number
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAbgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgXggIjwG4AoUSNHaCAQ3ggFc0BrNAewHcLaI16BbAEYgkQA)

In your case `string` and `string[]` are subtypes of `string | string[]` so no assertion to `unknown` is actually required.

More over since you are using `Array.isArray` which is a type guard no assertion is required at all:

```
function normaliseProps(props: string | string[]): string[] {
    if (Array.isArray(props)) {
        return props;
    } else {
        return [props];
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGOAnAtgQwDYwM4CmACqnAA54AUZpFAXInlKjGAOaIA+jzrbA2gF0AlAyYt2QxAG8AsAChESxDGCJKAQVSpMATwB0+LTt3VaeYcJkLltxKgJQQqJDXJ4A3DeUBfRAWxCa0U7JQcnF0R+NwpBLxClHwUfIA)